# Canvas rendering optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, d3.js, optimization

I have a maze and what I want is create a circle on every of its cell and then move those circles to the right side of the maze as the tree. I use d3 transitions and html5 canvas. My question is if there are any optimizations I can do. I don't know canvas performance so I don't know how much I can expect.

For 1600 elements (600 px x 600 px and 15px cellSize) the animation is smooth. For 3600 elements its not.

```
mazeSelection.selectAll('cell')
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append('cell')
    .attr('radius', 0)
    .attr('cx', d => d.data.ix * cellSize + 0.5 * cellSize,)
    .attr('cy', d => d.data.iy * cellSize + 0.5 * cellSize)
    .transition().duration(2000)
    .attr('radius', cellSize/2)
    .transition().duration(3000)
    .attr('radius', cellSize/4)
    .tween('position', function(d) {
        const i = d3.interpolate([this.getAttribute('cx'), this.getAttribute('cy')], [width + d.x, cellSize * 0.5 + d.y]);
        return (t) => {
            [d.cx, d.cy] = i(t);
            this.setAttribute('cx', d.cx);
            this.setAttribute('cy', d.cy);
        };
    });

context.fillStyle = "white";

let timer = d3.timer(function redraw() {
    // clear maze
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width * 2, height);

    //drawMaze(grid, context, width, height, cellSize);
    context.beginPath();

    // here we must use a function to have access to "this"
    mazeSelection.selectAll('cell')
        .each(function (d) {
            const radius = this.getAttribute('radius'),
                x = this.getAttribute('cx'),
                y = this.getAttribute('cy');

            context.moveTo(x, y);
            context.arc(x, y, radius * 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

            (d.children || []).forEach(child => {
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.lineTo(child.cx, child.cy);
            });
        });

    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
});
```

Comment: You're creating DOM elements here, best avoid that and create some list of javascript structures and then iterate through that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have 2 questions: 1. Even though I use append, the element doesnt appear in DOM tree when I use chrome dev tools. Are they so bad then? 2. Do you know maybe how to apply transition without DOM elements created?

Comment: 1. you can create more than on DOM tree, chrome dev tools may only be able to show you the one you've attached to the document. 1b) yes 2. recode per my initial comment.

Comment: 1. I understand. 2. Could you provide some simple example? D3 has convenient transistion method on selection and I don't know how to use it without appending anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go old school to get the best performance.

I will ignore the first half as i am not sure what you are doing with it. And i am guessing as to what this is in the `.each` iteration

What you are doing wrong in terms of performance as commented in your code below

```
// why use a let in global scope????
let timer = d3.timer(function redraw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width * 2, height);
    context.beginPath();

    // You wrote "here we must use a function to have access to "this""
    // What 'this'? I assume it is the iterated cell `this`. Just use the 
    // cell referance, you dont have to use `this`
    mazeSelection.selectAll('cell')
        .each(function (d) {     // dont use callbacks to iterate. For loops are much quicker
            // on chrome const and let are half the speed of var 
            const radius = this.getAttribute('radius'),  // why use getAttribute, a pointless and very CPU expensive way to get an object's property
                x = this.getAttribute('cx'),
                y = this.getAttribute('cy');
            // why even assign the above properties to a const when you can use them directly

            context.moveTo(x, y);
            context.arc(x, y, radius * 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

            // use a for loop and don't test for the existence of children 
            // by creating a new Array if they don't exist and then calling
            // the array method forEach, a complete waste of CPU time
            (d.children || []).forEach(child => {
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.lineTo(child.cx, child.cy);
            });
        });

    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
});
```

If you try the following to iterate the objects you will get some extra performance. Yet the 3000+ may still be out of reach.

```
var timer = d3.timer(function redraw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width * 2, height);
    context.beginPath();

    var cells = mazeSelection.selectAll('cell')
    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i ++){
        var d = cell[i];
        var x = d.x;  // create a local referance as x & y may be used many times
        var y = d.y;
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.arc(x, y, d.radius * 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        if(d.children){
            var c = d.children;
            for(var j = 0; j < c.length; j++){    
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.lineTo(c[j].cx, c[j].cy);
            }
        }

        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    };
```

If the arcs you are rendering are around the same size you may get some performance increase by rendering the arcs to an offscreen canvas (sprite sheet) and then drawing the arcs with `drawImage(spriteSheet,...` though depending on the hardware/browser this can be a minor or a significant performance increase

Comment: Thank for an answer! 1. What's exactly wrong with let in global scope? 2. I don't think attribute is cell's property as it seems to be undefined referenced as you showed. 3. Arcs have same size but they're moving. May I use drawImage in this situation?

Comment: 2. Ok I should just use `property()` instead of `attr()` in d3.

Comment: @JulianRubin `let` is half the speed of `var` on Chrome and as there is no dif between `let` and `var` in GS why use let?  Output to the console what you are iterating over `console.log(this)` and find out what `this` is.. Yes you can use `drawImage` for moving sprites. You should use direct reference rather than a function call (property or attr) they are just vetters.

Comment: @JulianRubin, these are tiny micro optimisation (still good to know though). Your real problem has been pointed out by robert's comment. Don't use DOM elements for canvas with d3. Use direct js objects. There should be no `select` in your code, no `append` no `attr`.

Comment: @Kaiido do you know any way to use d3 transistions with js objects? I don't know how to order object properties to change with transistions. I do select and attr because that's how I usually change data values over time.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.